# Wondering how to compare JDateChooser with LocalNow

Tags: java, datetime, date-comparison, jdatechooser, localdate

So I'm trying to create an if else statement where if a date from the jdatechooser is before today's date, then an error message would occur. From my knowledge, you can get today's date as LocalDate.now(), format it into a string, and then do a try-catch to parse it back into a Date. For the jdatechooser, you can grab that as a Date, format it into a string, and then do a try-catch to parse it back into a date as well. The only issue with this is when you do jdate.before(localdate) an error occurs. Is there another method of doing this? I saw that you could get today's date as an Instance, but I don't have much experience with that yet.

This is the code that I tried:

```
try {
    //Checks to see if New Due Date is a date set before today's date

    //Grabs today's date, converts it into string, then converts it into date
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    String tds = sdf.format(ld);
    Date tdd = sdf.parse(tds);

    //Grabs reactivateDateChooser1, converts it into string, then converts it into date
    Date rdc = reactivateDateChooser1.getDate();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    String rdcs = sdf1.format(rdc);
    Date rdcd = sdf1.parse(rdcs);

    //If the new Due Date is before or on today's date, then error message will show
    if(rdcd.before(tdd)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a date after " + tds, "Select Valid Date", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    //If the date chooser is empty, then error message will show
    else if (reactivateDateChooser1.getDate() == null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a date", "Needs Date", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    //Otherwise, if the new date is after today's date, then the function will happen
    else if (rdcd.after(tdd)){
        changeStatusToActive();
        statusCheck1.setText("");
        refreshClassTable();
        closeReactivateDialog();
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

And this is the error that I'm getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
```

Comment: When you can use classes from `java.time` such as `LocalDate`, go all-in and avoid outdated and troublesome classes like `SimpleDateFormat` completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
                = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ITALY);
    //Checks to see if New Due Date is a date set before today's date

    //Grabs today's date
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

    //Grabs reactivateDateChooser1, converts it into LocalDate (if not null)
    Date reactivateUtilDate = reactivateDateChooser1.getDate();

    //If the date chooser is empty, then error message will show
    if (reactivateUtilDate == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a date", 
                    "Needs Date", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        LocalDate reactivateDate = reactivateUtilDate.toInstant()
                    .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore"))
                    .toLocalDate();

        //If the new Due Date is before or on today's date, then error message will show
        //Otherwise, if the new date is after today's date, then the function will happen
        if (reactivateDate.isAfter(today)) {
            changeStatusToActive();
            statusCheck1.setText("");
            refreshClassTable();
            closeReactivateDialog();
        } else {
            String todayString = today.format(dateFormatter);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                        "Please select a date after " + todayString,
                        "Select Valid Date", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Rather than converting from the modern `LocalDate` to the outmoded `Date`, better to use the modern and better API as much as possible. I know you cannot avoid getting a `java.util.Date` from your `JDateChooser`, so first thing convert it to the modern `Instant` type and do further conversions from there to obtain a `LocalDate` that you can compare with the one you have. `LocalDate` has methods `isBefore` and `isAfter` for comparing to other `LocalDate` objects.

The old date and time classes `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and friends have proven to be poorly designed, and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular is notoriously troublesome. Just look at how many questions there are on Stack Overflow about surprising and unwanted behaviour of `SimpleDateFormat`. All of this is why Oracle issued `java.time` in 2014 as a replacement. And surely, the modern API is so much nicer to work with. I recommend it warmly.

I further recommend you specify locale for your formatter (even if you just specify `Locale.getDefault()`) and time zone for your conversion from `Date` to `LocalDate` (even if you go for `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. So no one needs to be in doubt that a locale and a time zone are used and you have chosen them consciously. Finally I have made an attempt at more explanatory variable names.

Comment: I gave an upvote to this even though it doesn't show. Thank you so much for helping me on this. I now understand to start using locale's for everything, even if I use getDefault(). The same goes with zoneId. As for date, simpledateformat, I'll start moving toward using the newer API that Oracle introduce. It's a shame that some of the answered questions on here are answers that used older material. Some even recommend using Joda Time, but on their site, they recommend to using the newer stuff. Also, thank you very much. Your instructions were insightful and easy to understand.

Comment: It’s a pleasure when one’s answer is so well received, @Xevon.

Answer (score 1):

**edited:**

After reading up on the Calendar and SimpleDateFormatter issues that Ole V.V. mentioned I realize that the solution I gave is not very good... Below is code using LocalDate and DateTimeFormatter:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy");
String output = ld.format(dtf);
```

**original:**

I can't speak to why Ole V.V. is telling you to avoid classes like SimpleDateFormat, I don't know enough about the subject matter. However, to achieve what you're trying to do, you can use:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
String tds = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

And that should work to get you the current time and date, and format it as you would like.